# Display AVplayer playback speed in macOS app

Tags: objective-c, avplayer

I'm starting from an apple demo app called [AVMovieEditor](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/AVMovieEditor/Introduction/Intro.html).  I'm trying to add a visual display of the playback speed.  Without any modification from me AVMovieEditor responds to the J,K & L keys like a video editing application.  J plays in reverse, J again plays faster in reverse, K is pause, L plays, L again plays faster, etc...

I've successfully created an observer however every time I check the `AVplayer.rate` it is either -1,0 or 1, despite playing faster than realtime.  Indeed when L is pressed the rate goes from 0 to 1, but then L is pressed a second time and the playback speeds up the rate changes back from 1 to 0?  The result is similar with J and reverse playback except the rate changes to -1 and then back to 0.

```
- (void)addPeriodicTimeObserver {
// about 30 times pr second
CMTime interval = CMTimeMake(33, 1000);
// Queue on which to invoke the callback
dispatch_queue_t mainQueue = dispatch_get_main_queue();
// Add time observer
self.timeObserverToken =
[self.movieViewController.playerView.player addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval:interval
                                          queue:mainQueue
                                     usingBlock:^(CMTime time) {
  NSLog(@"%f %f", 
    self.movieViewController.playerView.player.rate
    // only shows -1,0,1 despite playback faster then 100%
    [[self.movieViewController.playerView.player.currentItem.tracks[0] assetTrack] nominalFrameRate]);
    // Always shows 29.97
  }];
}
```

After much searching I am stumped as to how I can find a useful playback rate?

I'd like to know the actual frame rate of playback, and then I will make an indicator in my GUI to inform the end user the current playback rate.

---

Edit:  I've found another interesting bit of data, but it doesn't solve my problem...

`self.movieViewController.playerView.player.currentItem.tracks[0].currentVideoFrameRate`

When the above is observed upon starting playback it ramps up from 0 to 30ish, then when L is pressed a second time it ramps up to 60ish.  This would solve my problem but for 2 details.  First when L is pressed a third time video playback increases, but the `currentVideoFrameRate` still hangs around 60ish.  Second problem is that `currentVideoFrameRate` only shows positive values.  If J is pressed twice and `AVPlayer.rate` goes back to 0 from -1, there is no way of knowing the frames are traversing in reverse order!

One thing I have found no information on that I think might shed light on a solution is what entity is capturing the J,K & L keyboard events, and what response is being applied?

---

Edit2: Apple's quicktime player has the functionality I am looking for.  It responds to J,K & L like [AVMovieEditor](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/AVMovieEditor/Introduction/Intro.html) but it displays 2x, 5x, 10x, 30x & 60x respectively for it's playback speed and displays them on the left for reverse playback.  Is this something reserved for Apple only or can I have it too!?

---

Edit3: Based on an answer ( Thanks! ) I've started looking at another property `AVplayerItem.timebase.rate` However this is giving similarly incorrect results.

I can confirm that visually the players rate increases as expected with each press of the "L" key.  I would expect that also the "Requested Rate" ( `AVplayer.rate` ) I was using previously would also increase since I see it visually represented in playback, but not in the reported "Requested Rate".  ( it goes to 0 )

The "Playback Actually Occurring Rate" behaves similarly. Except that when I press a stop key, it still displays a rate of 1 presumably because the player was playing at the time of the request to stop.  But also `AVplayerItem.timebase.rate` reports an "Playback Actually Occurring Rate" of 0 when the playback rate is greater than 1 or less than -1.

This is the code I am currently using to see the rate.  It's triggered on an observer that watches for changes in the requested rate.  Is there a problem with how I am looking at these?

```
 NSLog(@"RequestedPlaybackRate:%f",myAVPlayer.rate);
 NSLog(@"OccuringPlaybackRate:%f",CMTimebaseGetRate(myAVPlayerItem.timebase));
```

I will clarify also that the "Requested Rate" is actually what I want, not the "Playback Actually Occurring Rate".

---

Edit4:

Created a github project for easy reproduction of this problem and submitted a bug report with Apple.

https://github.com/markjwill/AVPlayerRateBug

Comment: Programmer pain!  I thought I had this working at one point, but it's currently not working.  I start searching for a solution only to find my own post that I forgot I made :-(....

Answer (score 0):

AVPlayer.rate is the app's requested playback rate.

The rate at which playback is actually occurring is found with AVPlayerItem.timebase.rate

This is explained in detail in WWDC 2016 Session, "Advances in AVFoundation Playback"

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/503/?time=378